# Ruby : Loop, Case and iterations problems ( Rock , Paper, Scissors )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I´m ruby student since 1 month and i´m stuck with one part of my code. The project is based on a game ( rock, paper, scissor) but i´m facing of a problem that i cannot solve for moment. I would like to add one parameters to this game especially when the user enter a wrong input by displaying a message but with the condition i added it´s not working.

```
elsif player_choice != 'r' || player_choice != 'p' || player_choice != 's' || player_choice != 'q' || player_choice != 'x'
          puts "wrong input"
```

So if you have some advice or some hint to share with me it will be great ! ( see below the entire code ).

Thank you very much.

```
      #intro
    puts "***** WELCOME TO PAPER SCISSORS ROCKS GAME *****"

    puts "Input p = Paper, r = Rocks, s = Scissors, x = Display your score , q = Quit the game. "
    25.times { print "-" }
    puts

    #scores

    playerScore = 0
    cpuScore = 0

    CHOICES = {'p' => 'Paper', 'r' => 'Rock', 's' => 'Scissors', 'x' => 'score','q' => 'quit' }
    CHOICE_CPU = {'p' => 'Paper', 'r' => 'Rock', 's' => 'Scissors'}


    loop do

      # player picks
      begin 
        puts "Select your pick: (p/r/s/x/q)"
        player_choice = gets.chomp.downcase
      end until CHOICES.keys.include?(player_choice)

      # computer picks
      cpu_choice = CHOICE_CPU.keys.sample

    def throw_message(winning_choice)
      case winning_choice
      when 'p'
        puts "Paper wraps Rock!"
      when 'r'
        puts "Rock smashes Scissors!"
      when 's'
        puts "Scissors cuts Paper!"
      when 'x'
        puts "Live score"
      when 'q'
        puts "you decide to quit the game"
      end
    end

    #display scores
     if player_choice == 'x'
       throw_message(player_choice)
       puts  "PLAYER : #{playerScore} CPU : #{cpuScore}"

    #quit the game

    elsif  player_choice == 'q'
           throw_message(player_choice)
           break

    # tie result
    elsif player_choice == cpu_choice
        puts "It's a Tie ! "

    #player win

    elsif (player_choice == 'p' && cpu_choice == 'r') || (player_choice == 'r' && cpu_choice == 's') || (player_choice == 's' && cpu_choice == 'p')
        throw_message(playe·r_choice)
        puts "You Win"
        playerScore +=1

    #display invalid input

    elsif player_choice != 'r' || player_choice != 'p' || player_choice != 's' || player_choice != 'q' || 
   player_choice != 'x'
          puts "wrong input"

    #cpu win 

    else throw_message(cpu_choice)
          puts "Computer Win"
          cpuScore +=1


    end

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `CHOICES.keys.include?(player_choice)` check to the top of the main if/else logic. If you validate your input as early as possible, the rest of the code can assume the input is good; there's no need to spell out all the possible choices again.

I'm using a case/when because it's easier to read than if/elsif. `throw_message` is defined outside the loop, inside the loop its being redefined repeatedly. And I've removed choices from `throw_message` which don't have to do with the game; this avoids repeating the full set of choices.

```
def throw_message(winning_choice)
  case winning_choice
  when 'p'
    puts "Paper wraps Rock!"
  when 'r'
    puts "Rock smashes Scissors!"
  when 's'
    puts "Scissors cuts Paper!"
  end
end

def player_wins?(player_choice, cpu_choice)
  return player_choice == 'p' && cpu_choice == 'r') ||
         player_choice == 'r' && cpu_choice == 's') ||
         player_choice == 's' && cpu_choice == 'p')
end

loop do
  # player picks
  puts "Select your pick: (p/r/s/x/q)"
  player_choice = gets.chomp.downcase

  # cpu picks
  cpu_choice = CHOICE_CPU.keys.sample

  case
  when !CHOICES.keys.include?(player_choice)
    puts "wrong input"
  when player_choice == 'x'
    puts "Live score"
    puts  "PLAYER : #{playerScore} CPU : #{cpuScore}"
  when player_choice == 'q'
    puts "you decide to quit the game"
    break
  when player_choice == cpu_choice
    puts "It's a tie!"
  when player_wins?(player_choice, cpu_choice)
    throw_message(player_choice)
    puts "You Win"
    playerScore +=1
  else
    throw_message(cpu_choice)
    puts "Computer Win"
    cpuScore +=1
  end
end
```